# Compressing a stream from Azure Blob (Python SDK)

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Can I compress data from Azure Blob to gzip as I download it? I would like to avoid having all data in memory if possible.

I tried two different approaches (compress_chunk and compress_blob) functions. I am not sure if the entire blob was in memory though before compression, or if I can compress it as it is read in somehow.

```
def compress_chunk(data):
    data.seek(0)
    compressed_body = io.BytesIO()
    compressor = gzip.open(compressed_body, mode='wb')
    while True:
        chunk = data.read(1024 * 1024 * 4)
        if not chunk:
            break
        compressor.write(chunk)
    compressor.flush()
    compressor.close()
    compressed_body.seek(0, 0)
    return compressed_body

def compress_blob(data):
    compressed_body = gzip.compress(data.getvalue())
    return compressed_body

def process_download(container_name, blob):
    with io.BytesIO() as input_io:
        blob_service.get_blob_to_stream(container_name=container_name, blob_name=blob.name, stream=input_io)
        compressed_body = compress_chunk(data=input_io)
```

Comment: I don't suppose you ever figured out how to do this without reading everything into memory or a local storage?

Comment: I don't believe so. This might have started my journey with converting everything to Parquet files instead and I just let pyarrow handle the compression stuff

Comment: We're on the route with Parquet files but because of legacy support for now had to do this. I eventually came across a library called `smart_open` that helped me solve my problem. Definitely worth a shot to anyone who sees this comment. Using smart_open with gzip to compress blobs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you know how to compress data. So the following is just to make some clarifications.

> I am not sure if the entire blob was in memory though before
> compression.

When we need to download the blob data for processing, we use the official method to download the blob. At this time, it is in the form of a stream. It is not on the disk, but of course it will use the memory allocated by the program.

Azure didn't provide a method to pre-compress data on azure:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#methods

Therefore, when we want to process data, we must first download it, and when it is downloaded as a stream, it will of course take up memory.

Comment: And there is no way to compress "chunks" as they are downloaded? As I understand it, when you download data from a stream it is being downloaded in chunks bytes - I wonder if each chunk could be compressed to minimize the memory footprint?